# Error in Login in Titanium Studio

Tags: networking, aptana, titanium-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I installed Titanium Studio on my mac from along time and it was working very good without any error in login , and from 4 months I installed Aptana Studio to complete some works, now when I returned to use Titanium Studio again I couldn't login after re-installed of Titanium again and the following error appear during login , This problem have any relation to the Aptana Studio or in my network ?

[image: Login Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titanium Studio has been discontinued on June 1. You should have received several emails about this since March and seen a banner on the Studio Dashboard. You continue to use the Titanium CLI or switch to Appcelerator Studio: http://www.appcelerator.com

Comment: Thank you for your note , I installed Appcelerator Studio and it's working , but I want to ask about something , the Appcelerator Studio it's not free like Titanium Studio !

Comment: That's correct. Our free services now include the OSS Titanium CLI, SDK and Alloy. Our IDE (Studio) and Cloud services are now paid-only. You can start for free though, and only pay when you are ready to publish (and make money off) your app.